# Best way to transform JSON data within a Pandas dataframe into a dataframe itself

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

I have a Pandas dataframe where one column contains a non-nested json object in each row.

```
                             js
0  {"k1":"1","k2":"A","k3":"X"}
1  {"k1":"2","k2":"B","k3":"X"}
2  {"k1":"3","k2":"A","k3":"Y"}
3  {"k1":"4","k2":"D","k4":"M"}
```

Created like this:

```
import pandas as pd
L0 = ['{"k1":"1","k2":"A","k3":"X"}',
      '{"k1":"2","k2":"B","k3":"X"}',
      '{"k1":"3","k2":"A","k3":"Y"}',
      '{"k1":"4","k2":"D","k4":"M"}']
df = pd.DataFrame({'js':L0})
```

I want to make the json-objects into their own dataframe:

```
  k1 k2   k3   k4
0  1  A    X  NaN
1  2  B    X  NaN
2  3  A    Y  NaN
3  4  D  NaN    M
```

Right now the only way I know is by using the `json` module and `df.iterrows()`:

```
import json
all_json = []
for _,row in df.iterrows():
    all_json.append(json.loads(row["js"]))
df2 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(all_json)
```

Is there a better way to do this, ideally without iterating?

EDIT 1:

Thanks for the answers.

I have timed the three suggested approaches using `ast.literal_eval` on my real world data where my own approach takes `158 ms ± 4.01 ms`:

`df = df.apply(lambda x: ast.literal_eval(x[0]), 1).apply(pd.Series)` takes `640 ms ± 7.8 ms`

`df['js'].apply(ast.literal_eval).apply(pd.Series)` takes `636 ms ± 19 ms`

`pd.DataFrame(df.js.apply(ast.literal_eval).tolist())` takes `180 ms ± 5.11`

As suggested the third approach is the fastest, but sadly they are all slower than the `iterrows`-approach while my intention was to get rid of `iterrows` to make it faster.

EDIT 2:
`pd.DataFrame(df["js"].apply(json.loads).tolist())` takes `25.2 ms ± 512 µs` so we have a winner I guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would call the dataframe constructor after converting the string to dict ( *i think this would be faster*):

```
import ast
pd.DataFrame(df.js.apply(ast.literal_eval).tolist())
```

Or:

```
import json
pd.DataFrame(df["js"].apply(json.loads).tolist())
```

---

```
  k1 k2   k3   k4
0  1  A    X  NaN
1  2  B    X  NaN
2  3  A    Y  NaN
3  4  D  NaN    M
```

Comment: Thanks, but this approach is much slower than mine, see Edit.

Comment: @Khris how about `pd.DataFrame(df["js"].apply(json.loads).tolist())` ?

Comment: `25.2 ms ± 512 µs`, that's what I was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) and apply [`pd.Series`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.html) as:

```
import ast
df = df.apply(lambda x: ast.literal_eval(x[0]), 1).apply(pd.Series)

print(df)
  k1 k2   k3   k4
0  1  A    X  NaN
1  2  B    X  NaN
2  3  A    Y  NaN
3  4  D  NaN    M
```

OR:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([ast.literal_eval(i) for i in df['js']])
```

OR:

```
import json
df = pd.DataFrame([json.loads(i) for i in df['js']])
```

Comment: Thanks, but this approach is much slower than mine, see Edit.

Comment: @Khris Check my new approach.

Comment: Second one is faster, third one is as fast as the `to_list`-approach by @anky_91.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `apply(pd.Series)`:

```
import ast
print(df['js'].apply(ast.literal_eval).apply(pd.Series))
```

Output:

```
  k1 k2   k3   k4
0  1  A    X  NaN
1  2  B    X  NaN
2  3  A    Y  NaN
3  4  D  NaN    M
```

Comment: Thanks, this approach is almost as fast as mine, but sadly still slower.